# Unable to find Android SDK API 28 [Appcelerator Titanium]

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

I am trying to run my code on **Android emulator** in Appcelerator Titanium but error comes during compilation time.

**Error:
Unable to find Android SDK API 28**

I am running this code on latest Titanium SDK version **8.0.0.GA**

Screenshot:
[image]

I have downloaded Android SDK 28 API and created new Android emulator.
Still not fixed. Help.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `appc ti setup android` in a terminal is the PATH to your Android SDK correct?

I've also found in the past that there can sometimes be updated agreements that must be accepted in either XCode or Android Studio in order to proceed.

If you downgrade your Titanium SDK version to 7.X will it still build fine?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue and nothing helped. Install Android 9.0 (API 28) and things will work like a charm.

Comment: Hello where did you install the SDK I have everything installed in Android Studio and have the same path